# Unable to view the contents in USB in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I already tried so many times to give access to USB in VirualBox and unable to view contents in it.

[image: USB to view contents in USB in VirtualBox]

Comment: The photo is blurred. You can take screenshot of the guest os and post that

Comment: Do you have virtualbox extension pack installed and how did you try to access the usb?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager select your VM and click settings, then click USB.  You will see USB settings menu.  Check off Enable USB controller, select USB 2.0 Controller, click add new USB filter (the icon with the green plus) and choose your USB drive from the list.  With this filter in place when the guest starts up, it will attach this hardware to itself effectively taking it away from the host operating system.  Then click OK and start up your guest.

Make sure you have Virtualbox extension pack installed.